# Изменения только в коммите, а не локально

Tags: git, clion, форматирование, контроль-версий

Возможно ли делать форматирование при коммите, но при этом чтобы локально оставалось твоё форматирование?

Надо для того, чтобы каждый участник репа мог иметь свой стиль кода, но в итоговой кодовой базе использовать 1 конфиг clang-format.

Comment: Вы хотите невозможного.

Answer (score 2):

Нет. Форматирование кода это не какие-то метаданные, а такая же неотъемлемая часть текста в файле, как и сам код.

Может быть, можно настроить IDE так, чтобы при открытии файла автоматически применялись свои правила форматирования, но это уже местные локальные дела и с гитом никак не связано.

Comment: Есть такой "хак": коммитить при помощи скрипта, который сначла переносит изменённые файлы в отдельную временную директорию, там исправляет форматиование и уже потом делает "настоящий коммит". Правда, при каждом git pull форматирование будет ломаться у вас, потому что из репозитрия будут приезжать файлы с "чужими правилами форматирования"

Comment: @S.H.ну вы понимаете, что это не просто хак, а тихий ужас, и так делать никогда не надо!